# views slideshow caption with absolut position

Tags: views, javascript

I have created a views slideshow with images which are not equal in width and height. Under my slideshow i placed a global PHP field With some informations (Autor name , filename, exif data from the images..)
The Problem is that i cant place this block in an absolute position . it jumpes up or down cause my images are different in size. How can i make the block staying. I tried it with CSS position:absolut but it dont helped..

Comment: use image style for specific size

Comment: problem is that i want that the slideshow shows vertical images & horizontal images. That means i cant use image style

Comment: then use width:auto

Comment: the problem is the block (global textfield) below my slideshow it jumps up and down,depending on image. I want to place the block on the right from my slideshow. With Css i placed them there with position absolut but it still jumps up and down :-(

Comment: is there no possibility to avoid that all fields under a views slideshow jumping up and down depending on image heigh??